# Alternatives to reading Process output

Tags: c#, process, io

I would like to know if there are other alternatives to capturing a process output in C#. 
I have the following code

```
Process __process = new Process();
__process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
__process.StartInfo.FileName = "some file path here";
__process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
__process.Start();
__process.WaitForExit(300000);
```

The reason why UseShellExecute is set to true here is because that's required for the verb "runas" to run as administrator. As a result, I cannot redirect the standard output of the program anymore.
What are other ways that I can capture the output of Process if I can't use StandardOutput? I thought about making the program write to a file and then read from that file but that doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: While I do tend to strive for efficiency in my code... Will this process need to run often? Is the output going to be very large and take considerable time to read in? If not, then I would just stick with File I/O if you can

Answer (score 0):

If you can code the actual program you're starting the process to use pipes that would probably be the best / most efficient solution. There might be a way to have the process output piped by some other command/program.

[Pipe Operations in the .Net Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could create a named or [anonymous pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeserverstream(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass it's name/id/handle to the program as an argument. The program can then connect to the other end of the pipe and stream data back to your application that called it.

*EDIT* I'm assuming this is all running on a Windows environment, and I don't know if using pipes on a process started with `UseShellExecute = true` works..

Comment: I would not recommend pipes as first option to communicate across different accounts (note that OP needs that for "runas") due to need to handle security properly to get it working (especially without reasonable sample). Saving data to file as OP suggested if possible would be way easier/safer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed, saving to file is definitely going to be easier. I only suggested this since the OP had already considered using a file and can't capture standard output. I was a bit anxious to give an alternative